# Current Android Gradle Support on Eclipse?

Tags: android, android-studio, adt

Does anyone know if Eclipse's Android Gradle support is up to snuff or is it crazy not to go onto Android Studio?  Is Eclipse Android totally Jurrasic Park at this point?

Comment: I was sketchy about migrating at first too. But, if eclipse wasn't so hard to configure I never would have had to worry. Android Studio is far superior to Eclipse, and I've only been on AS for 3 months compared to years on Eclipse

Comment: Yeah, I've started learning about gradle and I'm quite enthused about it as a build environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As android studio is now the official IDE for android programming, and eclipse IDE is no longer officially supported, yes you should switch to android studio.

I wouldn't go as far as to call you crazy if you didn't, though. You can keep using eclipse if you prefer that IDE, but you'll miss out on future awesomeness.

From http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html:

> If you have been using Eclipse with ADT, be aware that Android Studio
>   is now the official IDE for Android, so you should migrate to Android
>   Studio to receive all the latest IDE updates

Comment: yes, gradle is a much better way to build software.  Especially complex builds like Android. The support in Studio is a lot better than Eclipse